# Using a button to move to the next record

Tags: php, html

I would like to move to the next record using an HTML button. I have tried for and foreach SQL statements I have also tried using num rows and calling the cells values.

```
$id=$_get['Badge ID  Number'];
    
    $sqlkc = "select * from Badges.BADGEMSTR";
            $result = mysqli_query($sqlc, $sqlkc);
                    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $BIDN= $row['Badge ID Number'];
                        $Fname= $row['First Name'];
                        $MI= $row['Middle Initial'];
                        $Lname= $row['Last Name'];
                    }
                    $next = next($result);
    ?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.
Forgot to add my current onclick command

```
onclick='<?php echo $next;?>'
```

All HTML code as requested

```
<table style="background-color: tan; margin: auto">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $BIDN;?>"/>
            <input type="text" value="01"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $Fname;?>"/>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $MI;?>"/>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $Lname;?>"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Next" style="float: right" onclick='<?php echo $next;?>'/></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Last" style="float: right" onclick='<?php echo $nextid;?>'/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I think you're mixing different things... HTML = clientside (browserside). PHP = serverside. SQL is run on the serverside. If you wanted to tie a button to the execution of SQL then clicking on the button needs to trigger PHP code on the server. You'll need some kind of counter parameter to track the offset.

Comment: Sorry i am trying to understand `$next` would be the php parameter that is called by the html button? granted the `next($result)` wont work

Comment: You would definitelly need a parameter from the table which you would pass between GET or POST calls. For example, if your table has auto increment key, you could use that param to pass between pages. If not, you can call your sql query with ORDER BY and order the badge id’s in ascending or descending order. Next, you could try writing sql query to give you the next larger badge id and limit the number of results to 1.

Comment: my badge id's are auto increment. would that be `$next = $_GET[Badge id] ++1` with next being the onclick command in the html button?

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add the HTML code you are currently using?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood the question right.

Since you would pass the Badge ID between pages, you should use prepared statements as such. So, taking the Badge ID Number is Integer, your PHP code should look like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(hostname,username,password,dbname);
if (isset($_GET['last_id'])) {             
    // Last row in the table
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT * FROM Badges.BADGEMSTR ORDER BY `Badge ID Number` DESC LIMIT 1');          
} elseif (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // Specific row in the table
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT * FROM Badges.BADGEMSTR WHERE `Badge ID Number`>? ORDER BY Rb ASC LIMIT 1');  
    $stmt->bind_param('d',$_GET['id']);        
} else {
    // First row in the table
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT * FROM Badges.BADGEMSTR ORDER BY `Badge ID Number` ASC LIMIT 1');  
}

// Execute the query and get the results
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_array();                        
    
// Initialize variables from the given $row
$BIDN = $row['Badge ID Number'];
$Fname = $row['First Name'];
$MI = $row['Middle Initial'];
$Lname = $row['Last Name'];
```

As for the HTML code, it's a bit unclear from the question, but I think something like this would be in order:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table style="background-color: tan; margin: auto">
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($BIDN, ENT_QUOTES); ?></td>
                <td>01</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($Fname, ENT_QUOTES); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($MI, ENT_QUOTES); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($Lname, ENT_QUOTES); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="path_to_the_php_script.php?id='.$row['Badge ID Number']; ?>">Next</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="path_to_the_php_script.php?last_id=1">Last</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

You also don't have to use inputs to display the results, you could show them between TD elements in the table like `<td><?php echo $row['Badge ID Number']; ?>`.

Comment: I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: I am sorry but it did not work. I made changes to the `$link` to connect to my database. I get a blank page and the table doesn't show up at all when i click next. The first record doesn't show up like it did with the original code.

Comment: @ventron, I'm so sorry to hear that. Since you told that table doesn't show up at all, I assume that something is wrong with your connection to the database. To inspect what error is occurring, you can add to the beginning of the PHP script these two lines     `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. This way the PHP will tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Meanwhile, you can check the snapshots I did just now. 
1. https://ibb.co/VxVkyxF , when you first call the script
2. https://ibb.co/pjqVRVK , when click Next
3. https://ibb.co/XWH52H4 , when you click Last.

Comment: I will check for errors and try to fix them i will let you know what happens. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Looks link its the `bind_param('d',&_GET['id']` its causing a fatal error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in /var/www/html/Cardnav.php:24 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/Cardnav.php on line 24

Comment: @ventron, I guess this is a typo, it isn't `&_GET`, it's `$_GET`.

Comment: yes it is sorry its correct in the code i just messed up typing it here